# Office Add-in Angular app by Yeoman generator: Component must have a template or templateUrl [with Webpack], even though it's declared

Tags: angular, webpack, office-js, angular-template, angular-language-service

We are using Webpack and Angular template with `require` syntax like below in officeJS Add-In.

```js
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id.toString(),
    selector: 'list',
    template: require('./list.html')
})
```

We are getting error `Component 'List' must have a template or templateUrl` on Component declaration.

I don't have much detail about Webpack, but with `templateUrl` application not working (might be because of with webpack/system.js), Application is not able to get HTML by `templateUrl` at runtime.

But core problem with above require syntax is I'm not getting intellisense in template HTML w.r.t associated component by Angular Language Service.

I found one open issue on GitHub for this require syntax https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23553

Considering solution for template syntax, Do we have any alternative solution where intellisense and webpack both can work together?

We are using Angular 4 and "webpack": "^4.41.5", but I think this issue exists for higher Angular version as well, based on above GitHub post.

**Recent Observation:**

I tried with new Angular Project from scratch for OfficeJS as per `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/word-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator` here as well facing same issue with default webpack configuration, seems there might be some limitation.

Comment: what raw-loader version do you use in package.json?

Comment: It seems we have consumed "file-loader": "^5.0.2" and "html-loader": "^0.5.5" only in webpack config, haven't used raw-loader, is it must to use?

Answer (score 0):

[Looking at the code of the current version (11.1.2)](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/11.1.2/packages/language-service/src/diagnostics.ts#L96) says that this error only occurs when

```
template === null && !templateUrl
```

Since you aren't passing in `templateUrl` then that must mean that `template` is null.

I don't know if this is the same issue but here are some things I had to work through to get this process working for me. It might shed some light on what your issues might be.

The `template` part assumes it is being passed a string so I had to figure out how to load the whole template into a string for that part of the component. Here is what I settled on.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import template from './foo.html'

@Component({
    selector: 'foo',
    template
})
export class FooComponent {}
```

Combined with the webpack `html-loader`, which exports html as string, this then loads the html into my javascript as a string for each component.

However, typescript didn't like this so I had to create a definition file for html so that it knew I was expecting it to a string.

```
declare module '*.html' {
    const _: string;
    export default _;
}
```

And with that in place everything works.

Comment: Hi @MatthewGreen, still after creating definition file for html and importing html as above, getting `Component 'AppComponent' must have a template or templateUrl` seems its still not able to locate html, and no intellisense in HTML for component functions (vice versa), just to mention I created custom typings file and imported in "typeRoots" of tsconfig.json

Comment: You might confirm that you are getting a string for your template. Maybe just a simple file with a console.log of your variable. It could be a problem with the way you have webpack set up.

Comment: In my case, I tried with new Angular Project from scratch for officeJS as per `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/word-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator` here as well facing same issue with default webpack configuration, seems there might be some limitation